# Why is spacetime in the adjoint representation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spacetime, supersymmetry, poincare-symmetry

Given the fermionic dimensions, it seems like naively speaking that real spacetime dimensions transform in the adjoint representation of the fermionic dimensions' generators which is a 3+1 dimensional representation.

Why is it so? Why not more complicated representations? What really forbids the existence of such representations?

Comment: Fermionic dimensions? what?

Comment: @Prahar a.k.a Grassmannian dimensions.

Comment: You're just rephrasing. What theory has fermionic/Grassmannian dimensions? What does mean physically?

Comment: Supersymmetry. Superspace. Are you familiar with the concepts?

Comment: Susy theories do not have fermionic dimensions. There are superpartners of fields. Superspace is a mathematical tool which allows us to describe susic theory in a nice language. It is not physical and I don't know of any theory which claims the fermionic coordinates of superspace are physical in any way. Also, superspace doesn't even exist for all susy theories. It can only be used to describe some  theories (eg, N=1 theories in four dimensions).

Comment: I'm not sure what you say is correct about the physicality of such dimensions as any mathematics used in physics has physical meaning. Superspace exists also for extended supersymmetries. page 109 https://people.sissa.it/~bertmat/susycourse.pdf 
though the author avoids the superspace formulation of N=2 SUSY.

Comment: I'm simply pointing out that I am not aware of any model which interprets these fermionic dimensions in any way beyond as a mathematical tool. If you would like to do this, then you are obviously free to do so, but this has not yet been done, afaik. Also, I never claimed that superspace doesn't exist for extended susy (I specifically used e.g. in the parenthesis). I am simply saying that superspace does not exist for all (in fact, most) susy theories so we can't think of it as a fundamental feature of susy theories.

Comment: Please leave some instances where superspace can't be defined for a susy theory.